# talib.ATR or other ATR calculation

Tags: volatility, programming, python

I have my data stored in `df1` with the columns: `Date Time Open High Low Close Vol OI`
I want to calculate the *20 period ATR* from my df1. Using [TA-Lib](https://www.ta-lib.org/) I have tried the following which gives an error:

```
todayATR = talib.ATR(df1['High'],df1['Low'],df1['Close'],timeperiod=20)
```

I am new to python so I might have missed something simple.

Answer (score 1):

`talib` functions do not accept `pandas` time series as inputs. Try

```
talib.ATR(df1['High'].values, df1['Low'].values, df1['Close'].values, timeperiod=20)
```

instead.